# Showing a graphic of a Cellular Automaton rule icon in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm working in Mathematica 9 and am attempting to show the graphic of the simple rule icons (0-255)

Here is the code that I got from `WolframMathWorld`:

```
Show[Graphics[ElementaryCARules[30, {-2, 21}, 1.3]],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 450]
```

I've tried variations of it but always get a pink square.

I have looked at all the Mathematica documentation concerning `Cellular Automata` as well as going to `WolframAlpha` and checking the code their.

Any help out there?

Comment: Is the name `ElementaryCARules` displayed in blue in the notebook you are working in ?

Comment: Yes....which tells me it is not a recognizable function. Maybe because it is old legacy notation that Mathematica 9 doesn't read and has been updated to something else?

Answer (score 0):

By "graphic of the simple rule icons" do you mean this

```
RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[30]]
```

[image]

Comment: `RulePlot` was added in Wolfram Language version 11. OP is using version 9 so will have to upgrade.